# Window in cascade not raised to top when selected

Tags: windows, wxwidgets

I have an app which creates a series of modeless dialog windows which are shown in a 'cascade.  The user is supposed to be able to click on any window to bring it to the top and interact with it.

Here's a screenshot, showing this working as intended.  The user has clicked on the window 3rd from the bottom, successfully bringing it to the top.

[image]

A user reports that when he runs this, and clicks on one of the obscured window then the window *does not rise to the top*.

[Here is a video](http://www.screencast.com/t/2M4QyTSMpBY) showing the problem occurring.  It shows a normal cascade of notebook windows, behaving as expected.  Then a cascade of my application windows appears, but the user cannot bring any selected window to the top.  The selected window changes appearance, indicating that it has been selected, but it remains obscured.  ( The video concludes by demonstrating a related problem, which we can probably ignore for now )

The user reports that this problem occurs on other PCs he has tried.  I cannot reproduce the problem.

I am completely stumped and cannot even guess what might be causing this.

( One theory I had was that the app had frozen and was no longer responding to paint messages.  However, the video shows the user dragging the obscured window out of the cascade, and then the window is painted just fine.  It seems clear that the app does not get a paint message, or ignores it, when the window is selected )

The app is written using C++ and wxWidgets 2.9.4 and runs under windows 7

This appears to be a wxWidgets 2.9 issue.  When built with v2.8.12 libraries, the user reports that it works fine.

Here is the code to create the windows.  Note that the parent is NULL.  ( This allows the main application window to be minimized without minimizing the cascade windows - a required feature. )

```
cNewDataPopup::cNewDataPopup(  cPatDataset& data )
    : wxDialog(NULL,-1,L"New data",wxPoint(200,200),wxSize(570,242),
        wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE|wxSTAY_ON_TOP )
    , myData( data )
{
```

Comment: What styles and parent do you use for your windows?

Comment: @VZ added code fragment showing parent and styles used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, I found that adding wxDIALOG_NO_PARENT to the wxSTAY_ON_TOP 'fixes' the problem.

( The following explanation is due to VZ. )

Apparently, specifying the window's parent as NULL is not sufficient to convince wxWidgets that you want no parent.  It goes ahead and assigns a parent anyway, more or less at random.  This is why odd, unexpected and unreproducible behaviour is observed.  The algorithm for assigning a parent was changed in v2.9.x, which is why the odd and unexpected behaviour changes when I upgraded wxWidgets.  In order to convince wxWidgets that, yes, really, I do not want a parent for a window, I have to specify BOTH a NULL parent and the wxDIALOG_NO_PARENT style.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I didn't notice/realize that you used `wxDialog` and not `wxFrame` for your windows -- why? Anyhow, you do need to use `wxDIALOG_NO_PARENT` for the dialogs to prevent them automatically selecting some existing window as their parent, which means that you had some very convoluted parent-child relations in the first version. Sorry for `wxSTAY_ON_TOP` comment, it's almost surely blameless here.

Comment: I used wxDialog rather than wxframe because I think of these windows as dialogs, not as applications.  Also, because I do not need to create a panel to hold the controls.  Do you have any idea why this was unnecessary in 2.8.12, but is necessary on some machines in 2.9.4?

Comment: I don't remember any changes in 2.8, but the algorithm for finding the right parent for a dialog was tweaked a bit to do the more correct thing there, so maybe this explains it.

Comment: @VZ If you edit your answer to provide the correct solution, I will accept it.

Comment: It's OK, I didn't answer it -- you did.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `wxSTAY_ON_TOP` is almost certainly the culprit. If you just need the windows to stay on top of the parent window, don't use this style, either use `wxFRAME_TOOL_WINDOW` or override `WM_SIZE` handling by overriding `MSWWindowProc()` in your parent frame.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I will try wxFRAME_TOOL_WINDOW.  My client does not work Sundays and I cannot reproduce the problem on any of my machines, so it will be some time until I know if this helps any.

Comment: The client reports that replacing wxSTAY_ON_TOP with wxFRAME_TOOL_WINDOW  changes the behaviour some in the right direction, but does not solve the problem.